# TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta microseconds component: InstrumentedAttribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

i am also getting error while doing this task.

Models.py

CloudImageMaster

```
created_tmstmp = Column(DateTime(), default = datetime.now(timezone.utc))
```

ClientMaster

```
ttl = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)
```

QUERY:-

```
db.query(CloudImageMaster).join(ClientMaster).filter(
    (
    CloudImageMaster.created_tmstmp + timedelta(microseconds=ClientMaster.ttl)
    ) < today
).all()
```

ERROR MESSAGE :-

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta microseconds component: InstrumentedAttribute
```

I tried above. It should work as per the code. What i am doing wrong in this.

Comment: can you explain it a bit more. If you can write correct statement.

Comment: we are using Postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a filter expression like `MyMode.attr == something`, the left hand side (LHS) can be thought of as belonging to the database side, the right hand side (RHS) as belonging to the application.  What this means is that the RHS must be expressed in what SQLAlchemy regards as database constructs (ORM entities, tables, columns, database functions) while the LHS is expressed as normal Python code.

This means that we can't subtract a `timedelta` (a Python construct) from a `Datetime` column (a database construct); we have to convert the `timedelta` to a database construct - a PostgreSQL interval. We can do this by using the [make_interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) function, dividing `ttl` by 1000 as `make_interval` does not accept a microsecond argument.

```py
from sqlalchemy import func

db.query(CloudImageMaster)
  .join(ClientMaster)
  .filter(
      (
          CloudImageMaster.created_tmstmp
          + func.make_interval(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ClientMaster.ttl /1000)
      ) < today
  ).all()
```